# When I run vba macro nothing happens?

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have the below code in my excel file, but when I run it nothing happens and it doesnt come up in window either.

```vb
    GetDataFromADO()

        'Declare variables'
            Dim objMyConn As ADODB.Connection
            Dim objMyCmd As ADODB.Command
            Dim objMyRecordset As ADODB.Recordset

            Set objMyConn = New ADODB.Connection
            Set objMyCmd = New ADODB.Command
            Set objMyRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset

        'Open Connection'
            objMyConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Password=*******;User ID=*****; Initial 
        Catalog=*******; Data Source=*********************,1433;"
            objMyConn.Open

        'Set and Excecute SQL Command'
            Set objMyCmd.ActiveConnection = objMyConn
            objMyCmd.CommandText = "SELECT wh_id,mst_ship_num, cus_name, car_id, vsl_id,late_ship_dt, 
        load_cmpl, dsp_dt,live, ckin_dt,driver_arr_dte   FROM [dbo].[CXU_ALL_LOAD_CONTROL] WHERE wh_id = 
        'U07S' And dsp_dt = '2019-12-31'"
            objMyCmd.CommandType = adCmdText

        'Open Recordset'
            Set objMyRecordset.Source = objMyCmd
            objMyRecordset.Open

        'Copy Data to Excel'
            ActiveSheet.Range("A5").CopyFromRecordset objMyRecordset

   End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]! Missing definition of `GetDataFromADO` (Sub ot Function) Recordset misses connection! Try `Set objMyRecordset = objMyCmd.Execute`to open rs or dump command object.

Comment: Where do I need to add that line? or does it need to replace the set objMyRecordset.source=objMyCmd

Comment: Replace the two lines after `Open Recordset`comment.

Comment: I did that and it brought it up in the list of macros but it didnt pull any data in

Comment: Update your post to show the what changes you made that still aren't working.

Comment: Did what? Declared as Function? [Debug](https://riptutorial.com/excel-vba/example/8020/debugger-locals-window) code.

Comment: Set objMyRecordset = objMyCmd.Execute